# How to install Google Voice Action on emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, voice

Ho do I install the new [Google Voice Actions](http://www.google.com/mobile/voice-actions/index.html) on the emulator?

Android Market is not available on emulator. I found one APK at [android.modaco.com](http://android.modaco.com/content/software/315754/google-voice-actions-updated-quick-search-box-apks-original-testsigned/), but it's not working. The application crashes with following error (via ddms.bat):

```
08-13 22:44:51.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 22:44:51.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434): Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: GoogleSettingsProvider not found
08-13 22:44:51.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.LocationUtils.createLocationUtils(LocationUtils.java:48)
08-13 22:44:51.658: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(434):     at com.google.android.voicesearch.RecognitionActivity.onCreate(RecognitionActivity.java:386)
```

Alternatively, my questions question is where do I get official *.apk file for installing on emulator?

Comment: What version of the sdk are you running in the emulator?